# Illegal char <:> at index 1: \:PayPalDataCollector\build\libs\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF

Tags: android, android-studio

How to resolve Illegal char <:> at index 1: :PayPalDataCollector\build\libs\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF in android studio

Comment: Are you using BrainTree? Try downgrading to version 2.14.2, we had our dependency set as 2+ like the docs say but the 2.15.0 update today seems to have broken our guys working on Windows machines

Comment: I'm using this  implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.+' dependency but its not working fine and showing same error.

Comment: This question is valid. We have same problem. @hibob Thanks for your help

Comment: Full disclosure, I work at Braintree. We're aware of the issue and working toward a resolution. If you have any further questions, please contact support at https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact

Comment: This is resolved in the [Android v2.15.1 SDK](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2151). Please upgrade to resolve the issue.